# Using inline Assembly in C: Assigning labels in data segment

Tags: c, assembly, pascal

I was reading a tutorial on printing characters in assembly for the VGA-256 colors in DOS. The tutorial I was reading is written in Pascal, I have little experience in this language and all my VGA programs are in C.

My question is regarding a label used to access the bitmaps of each character. In pascal they have this:

```
procedure chr6x7_dat; assembler;
asm
  db  $00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$20,$20,$20,$20,$00,$20,$00,$50
  db  $50,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$50,$f8,$50,$50,$f8,$50,$00,$20,$f8,$a0
  db  $f8,$28,$f8,$00,$c8,$d0,$20,$20,$58,$98,$00,$40,$a0,$40,$a8,$90
  db  $68,$00,$20,$40,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$20,$40,$40,$40,$40,$20,$00
  db  $20,$10,$10,$10,$10,$20,$00,$50,$20,$f8,$20,$50,$00,$00,$20,$20
  db  $f8,$20,$20,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$60,$20,$40,$00,$00,$00,$f8,$00
  db  $00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$60,$60,$00,$00,$08,$10,$20,$40,$80
  db  $00,$70,$88,$98,$a8,$c8,$70,$00,$20,$60,$20,$20,$20,$70,$00,$70
  db  $88,$08,$70,$80,$f8,$00,$f8,$10,$30,$08,$88,$70,$00,$20,$40,$90
  db  $90,$f8,$10,$00,$f8,$80,$f0,$08,$88,$70,$00,$70,$80,$f0,$88,$88
  db  $70,$00,$f8,$08,$10,$20,$20,$20,$00,$70,$88,$70,$88,$88,$70,$00
  db  $70,$88,$88,$78,$08,$70,$00,$30,$30,$00,$00,$30,$30,$00,$30,$30
  db  $00,$30,$10,$20,$00,$00,$10,$20,$40,$20,$10,$00,$00,$f8,$00,$f8
  db  $00,$00,$00,$00,$20,$10,$08,$10,$20,$00,$70,$88,$10,$20,$00,$20
  db  $00,$70,$90,$a8,$b8,$80,$70,$00,$70,$88,$88,$f8,$88,$88,$00,$f0
  db  $88,$f0,$88,$88,$f0,$00,$70,$88,$80,$80,$88,$70,$00,$e0,$90,$88
  db  $88,$90,$e0,$00,$f8,$80,$f0,$80,$80,$f8,$00,$f8,$80,$f0,$80,$80
  db  $80,$00,$70,$88,$80,$98,$88,$70,$00,$88,$88,$f8,$88,$88,$88,$00
  db  $70,$20,$20,$20,$20,$70,$00,$10,$10,$10,$10,$90,$60,$00,$90,$a0
  db  $c0,$a0,$90,$88,$00,$80,$80,$80,$80,$80,$f8,$00,$88,$d8,$a8,$88
  db  $88,$88,$00,$88,$c8,$a8,$98,$88,$88,$00,$70,$88,$88,$88,$88,$70
  db  $00,$f0,$88,$88,$f0,$80,$80,$00,$70,$88,$88,$a8,$98,$70,$00,$f0
  db  $88,$88,$f0,$90,$88,$00,$70,$80,$70,$08,$88,$70,$00,$f8,$20,$20
  db  $20,$20,$20,$00,$88,$88,$88,$88,$88,$70,$00,$88,$88,$88,$88,$50
  db  $20,$00,$88,$88,$88,$a8,$a8,$50,$00,$88,$50,$20,$20,$50,$88,$00
  db  $88,$50,$20,$20,$20,$20,$00,$f8,$10,$20,$40,$80,$f8,$00,$60,$40
  db  $40,$40,$40,$60,$00,$00,$80,$40,$20,$10,$08,$00,$30,$10,$10,$10
  db  $10,$30,$00,$20,$50,$88,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$f8
  db  $00,$f8,$f8,$f8,$f8,$f8,$f8
end;
```

I would like to have a similar label in C so I can access it in my inline assembly command to calculate the offset depending on the ASCII value. However I have no idea how can I declare what I posted above in C.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: It's unclear what you want. That looks like a simple array to me.

Comment: It's an constant array in the code segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pascal `$` char is used to define [hexadecimals](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Hexadecimal)

If you want to define it in [c](/questions/tagged/c) simply create an array/matrix of `uint8_t` and init it with pascal values substituting `$` with `0x`

`$F5` will be `0xF5`

Comment: Thank you very much. The syntax was my problem. I have one more question. If I declare an array like the one you mentioned, will I be able to access it on inline assembly? I´m thinking of using an assembly code similar to this one:
`lea  si,the_array`      
`add  si,ax           { SI points to the bitmap }`     
`mov  cl,7                 `     
`segCS lodsb          { next byte from the bitmap }`

Comment: @PabloEstrada I'm not familiar with assembly, but it looks good.

Comment: That is 16-bit assembler. Are you creating 16-bits dos applications ?

Comment: LPs: The OP post doesn't have 16-bit assembler, in it.this thread does

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort ok, but is Pablo warned about your comment? I mean the question is for OP, I guess..

Comment: Yes the program uses 16 bit assembly. Thank you very much.